# Ads javascript code into meteor app

Tags: javascript, android, css, meteor, ads

I created meteor app under android environment, and I want to add ads javascript code to my app.

The image of ads is appeared on app main screen, but when I click on it, nothing happened, it doesn't open the related page over internet browser.

**The code is:**

```
<SCRIPT SRC="http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm? pid=740662&bid=1830650" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Hmm. I think you're missing the code...

Comment: Please add more details. template codes how you are implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

This must work :

```html
 meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.5.4

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://bdv.bidvertiser.com/BidVertiser.dbm?pid=740662&bid=1830650', '_system');">Link</a>
```